# javascript addEventListener and alert box

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function fire()
{
document.getElementById("submit1").addEventListner("click",sub,false);
}
function sub()
{
window.alert("submited");
}
window.addEventListener("load",fire,false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<input type="button" name="cal" value="Calculate" id="submit1"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where is the error in my code because I am not familiar with addEventListener method, can I know what is the difference between addEventListner and onsubmit ? addEventlistener must use in my code but I am familiar with onsubmit method only, how to change it to addEventListenr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
document.getElementById("submit1").addEventListner("click",sub,false);
document.getElementById("submit1").addEventListener("click",sub,false);
```